# Defining a functor instance for this datatype

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm attempting to define a functor instance for datatype `Terms`, which looks like:

```
data Terms a = Var a | App (Terms a) (Terms a) | Abs (Terms (Maybe a)) 
                     | Const Integer | Add (Terms a) (Terms a) 
                     | IfZero (Terms a) (Terms a) (Terms a) | Y
deriving (Show,Eq)
```

However, I'm having trouble with the case for `Abs`.

My definition currently looks like this:

```
instance Functor Terms where
    fmap f (Var x) = Var (f x)
    fmap f (App t1 t2) = App (fmap f t1) (fmap f t2)
    fmap f (Abs t) = Abs (fmap f t)
    fmap f (Const n) = Const n
    fmap f (Add t1 t2) = Add (fmap f t1) (fmap f t2)
    fmap f (IfZero t1 t2 t3) = IfZero (fmap f t1) (fmap f t2) (fmap f t3)
    fmap f Y = Y
```

I've tried several different things to get around the `Maybe` in order to apply the function to the term, but there's just something I'm not quite getting. I know the `Maybe` type is a functor on its own which means that `fmap` should work on it automatically, I'm just not sure how to work around the fact that it can't return as a `Maybe`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from this line:

```hs
fmap f (Abs t) = Abs (fmap f t)
```

`Abs` contains a `Maybe (Term a)`, and you want to get a `Maybe (Term b)`, but `f` is of type `a -> b`. So, when you try to `fmap` it, you're passing a `Term a` to a function that takes in `a`. Clearly this doesn't work. Instead, make a `Term a -> Term b` with `fmap f`, then `fmap` that (creating a double `fmap`):

```hs
fmap f (Abs t) = Abs (fmap (fmap f) t)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes `Maybe` is a functor on its own and thus it has *its own* `fmap`:

```
    fmap f (Abs t) = Abs (fmap₁ (fmap₂ f) t)

-- t               :: Terms (Maybe a)
--              f  ::              a  ->              b
--        fmap₂ f  ::        Maybe a  ->        Maybe b
-- fmap₁ (fmap₂ f) :: Terms (Maybe a) -> Terms (Maybe b)
```

The subscript indices are not part of the code and are there for illustrative purposes only. Or we could use `TypeApplications` to distinguish them:

```
*Main> :set -XTypeApplications
*Main> fmap @Maybe (+1) $ Just 7
Just 8
*Main> fmap @Terms (+1) $ Abs $ Var $ Just 8
Abs (Var (Just 9))
```

but there's no need for them here and plain `fmap`s work as well -- Haskell knows which to apply, according to the argument's type:

```
*Main> fmap (+1) $ Just 7
Just 8
*Main> fmap (+1) $ Abs $ Var $ Just 8
Abs (Var (Just 9))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to move the composition structure into a datatype by turning `Terms (Maybe a)` into `Scoped Terms a`. Your `Functor Terms` instance stays the same.

Instead composition happens in `Functor (Scoped exp)`, derived via the composition of `exp` and `Maybe` ([`Compose exp Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html)). This is how `fmap = fmap . fmap` is derived (modulo newtype wrapping).

```
{-# Language DerivingVia #-}

type    Scoped :: (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)
newtype Scoped exp a = Scoped (exp (Maybe a))
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Alternative, Foldable, Arbitrary1, ..)
  via Compose exp Maybe
```

This is the approach taken by Edward Kmett's [bound](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound) library.

[`Bound.Scope.Scope`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound-2.0.4/docs/Bound-Scope.html#t:Scope):

```
type    Scope :: Type -> (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)
newtype Scope bound exp free = Scope (exp (Var bound (exp free)))
```

[`Bound.Scope.Simple.Scope`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound-2.0.4/docs/Bound-Scope-Simple.html#t:Scope):

```
type    Scope :: Type -> (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)
newtype Scope bound exp free = Scope (exp (Var bound free))
```

where [`Var` = `Either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound-2.0.4/docs/Bound-Var.html#t:Var):

```
type Var :: Type -> Type -> Type
data Var bound free
  = B bound -- this is a bound variable
  | F free  -- this is a free variable
```